# Fit objects into certain size in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, photoshop-scripting, resize

I have 20 logos with different sizes. I would like them all to fit (maintaining proportions) into certain size – let's say limit both width and height by 100px. So that they can be later redistributed into a grid by another script, which will look ok.

Example: Original 2048*1024 should scale down proportionally to 100*50.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question - I found a script that resizes objects to fit the artboard size. It copies them and moves them to 0,0 coordinates by the way.

Here's the script: [Adobe Illustrator script to resize objects proportionally to fit inside the artboard.](https://gist.github.com/ruandre/7b47cbf2a4c55dac9adb)

Answer (score 0):

The [copy to object/ copy to objects](http://www.wundes.com/JS4AI/) scripts might help you if you create squares the size you want the objects to be

Comment: This basically replaces the content of original logo by the topmost object - it does something really different..